Really URGENT Problem with Electrum for Android
I have a really URGENT and complex Electrum issue on my Android Phone (Huawei P30 Pro with still official Google Play Services on it).
HOW do I turn my Electrum Hot-Wallet from ~2017 on my Huawei Android P30 Pro back to a "normal functioning" wallet where I can easily make transactions without needing a co-signer (which also doesn't work properly, or I might be doing it wrong)? The problem is that it’s been over 7 years, and I can't find my 12-word backup anymore. It also seems that there are no private addresses anymore, which disappeared after 2 years of not using the wallet. Maybe they are still somewhere on the phone, but I don't know where exactly. I have a few hundred on it, and I need that. This is very urgent to me because I have to pay my invoices, and Christmas is coming.
It's a native segwit (which wasn't there before either, or is this the watch-only?) with a shown public Keyphrase (zpub) with bip32. I know the Seed Password, but since the update, I only get a long Passphrase which only allows me to create a Watch-Only Wallet, it seems. Before that, I had the private addresses, and everything was running as normal as it should be, but now I can't get my money out or even transfer it to a newly created wallet.
I've bought coins, and these are now on an address. But when I want to make a transaction (no matter how high), I get a QR Code that says it's a partially signed transaction which I have to present to the Co-Signer. And under it, there's a yellow box that says something about: "Warning: Some Data (TXs before / 'full UTXOs') were not 'added' at all, because they didn't have enough space. This could cause a problem when it comes to the Offline-Signing. To avoid that problem, use the Copy and Paste Function or the Share Function."
Like I wrote, there is money/coins on it, but I don't know if it matters if they're "On-Chain" with a blue BTC symbol and above the money I had in EUROS. But if it helps, all transactions I made over the past years are still in the "used" addresses folder, and the address I got my money on 2 months ago is there too.
It would even be enough if somebody could help me transfer it to another fully new wallet. PLEASE, be kind. I'm so frustrated and can't get my money back or transfer it. I also don't know where/if the private keys are still saved on the phone anywhere. PLEASE HELP ME. I even wanted to contact the programmer of Electrum to see if they could help me somehow. I have too little knowledge about these kinds of things.
My current Electrum Version is 4.5.8, Protocol Version 1.4, Qt Version 6.4.3, PyQt Version 6.4.2, License WITH License. PLEASE HELP ME. I have no ideas or nerves left anymore.
Best Regards,
Dan
Oh, and over the field where you can read the Seed with the Password, there was always that Symbol "Encrypted" too. After the update, it's not there anymore. It seems like the update crashed the whole wallet. :/

Hey Dan, there is a lot going on in your post. Could you please proofread and format your post a bit to make it easier to read? If I understand right, your Electrum wallet was a full wallet and turned into a watch-only wallet. What happened in between? Did you uninstall the app or was it installed throughout?

Hey. I will try to make it more readable. Yes, correct, it seems so. Inbeteeed the App was inactive for 2 Years and did automaticly an Update over Google Play Store (which i have turned on to scan always for harmful Updates). Then it was on Version 4.5.7. and i wanted to use it again as im always did, you can see that I had the last made transaction 2 Years before. I opened it and buyed Bitcoins from where I always buy, It came without Problems and now I can do nothing with it. Always get the same output to need a co-signer for and yeah, i tried with all i could find but no chance. Regards

Oh and the 12 Words are NOW an very long Passphrase which i've never set on Setting up the Wallet 7 Years ago

And no, it was all the time at the same phone....

Hey Dan, I tried to help by doing some spell-checking and updating the formatting. Unfortunately, I’m not familiar with Electrum on Android, and especially not with upgrade bugs. I would recommend that you reach out to the Electrum developers directly as this probably needs some expert help.

Thank you @Murch i didn't had time, but now I have.

Yeah, I have...but they don't answer at all :(

I've wrote ThomasV on 2 different Mail-Adresses and the other one which I don't remmber the Name of...but no answer, no help, nothing :( For his own Product.....

Just to be clear, you are contacting open source developers that are donating their time to offer free software. They are in no way obligated to help you, so keep that in mind about the way you approach this topic. Given that it’s the weekend before Christmas, it may well be the case that they only find time after Christmas. Potentially a better contact point would be to file an issue on their GitHub repository: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/new

I mean it is there Product what they've created, and I was getting ignored, no Answer, no Hint, how should I fix that Bug if I'm not even a Programmer at all. And this makes me sad, because the Mail was 2 Weeks ago. And to the other Programmer maybe 1 Week. :(

I have, probably 1 or 2 Month ago, i got no help at all. And i be friendly, write friendly, i'm just frusrtrated at this point. Sry

To be frank, if your email was of the same quality as your post here originally, I could see why they would have felt that it was too much work to respond. Electrum is a self-custodial wallet. It’s licensed under MIT: "The software is provided 'as is' without any warranty of any kind". It’s the user’s responsibility to keep a backup and use it correctly. If their update broke your wallet, they will probably feel like they should help, but if I were you, I’d try to make it as easy as possible for them, and make them feel that it’s a good use of their time.

I know what you mean, and i've gaved them the Link to this Discussion, it was 1 Supporter, who wanted to help, but I think he wasn't an expert at all, we just made an Software Update from .7 to .8 (the last one). And he didn't knew further. And that was it. I used the Wallet Corrrect, have an Backup but could not find it at all, i've used the Wallet correctly, but after I opened it 2 Years after it was in this condition. And I sat here day and night, researched, tried these and that....i mean it is unfortunley a matter of 30min for them of less to fix it that I get my Money out which I'm NEED.
